# Bootstrap Modal not working for all records in table

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I have made a bootstrap modal for updating each record in the table individually using a while loop in PHP, but it seems to work only for the first record of the table. I'm not being able to figure out where I'm going wrong. Please help me with it let me know where I'm going wrong.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM fee_status";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $i = 1;
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width='5%'><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
      <td width='20%'><?php echo $row["student_id"]; ?><br><?php echo $row["student_name"]; ?></td>
      <td width='10%'><?php echo $row["fee_due"]; ?></td>
      <td width='25%'>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' id='dropdownMenuButton' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>Actions</button>
          <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'>
            <a class='dropdown-item' data-toggle='modal' data-target="#myModal<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>">Update Payment</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
      <div class="modal" role="dialog" id="myModal<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="max-width: 65%;">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Update Payment</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="update_payment_form" class="form-group" action="update_fee.php" method="post">
                  <div class='form-group required'>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        Student Details: <input type="text" name="student_details" value='<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?> - <?php echo $row['student_name']; ?>' style='width: 70%;' readonly>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        Amount: <input type="number" name="new_payment" placeholder='<?php echo $row['fee_due']; ?>' style='width: 40%;' required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="date-field" type="date" name="date" style='width: 40%;'>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="form_submit()" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php
      }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```